# disable isort check for 2 empty lines before <anything>

Tags: python, isort

How can I disable `isort` check for 2 empty lines before `<anything>`

```
import sys

class Person:
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = "moish"
```

I tried with telling `isort` to ignore whitespace but that didn't help:

```
$ isort -ws main.py
Fixing /home/oren/main.py <----- arrrggghhh leave spacing to me
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `--lines-after-imports` argument

Comment: `$ isort --lines-after-imports=1 main.py` works, but I'm looking for a complete disable of the check.

Comment: you can inspect the isort cli arguments here: https://github.com/PyCQA/isort/blob/a129f7fb7ce24b72978a3e905a08a1c46dd5ecbc/isort/main.py#L133

Comment: seems the option of disabling this check doesn't exist there - am I right?